# Beamer overlay specifications with genealogytree?

Tags: beamer, overlays, genealogytree

Is there a way I can use beamer overlay specifications with options in genealogytree? In this example I want to first show a tree and next show the same tree with an option "highlight" applied to one node. Instead of having this as two frames, how can I write it so that `[highlight]` is only used for `<2>`?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}

\gtrset{highlight/.style={box={colback=yellow!20}}}

\begin{document}
\frame{
  \frametitle{Example}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \genealogytree[template=signpost]{
      parent{
        p{father}
        p{mother}
        g{child}
      }
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\frame{
  \frametitle{Example}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \genealogytree[template=signpost]{
      parent{
        p{father}
        p{mother}
        g[highlight]{child}
      }
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\only` but help the tree parser a bit by moving it outside the tree.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}

\gtrset{highlight/.style={box={colback=yellow!20}}}

\begin{document}

  \newcommand\tmp[1]{%
    \genealogytree[template=signpost]{
        parent{
        p{father}
        p{mother}
        g[#1]{child}
  }}}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Example}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
        \only<1>{\tmp{}}%
        \only<2>{\tmp{highlight}}%
  \end{tikzpicture}
  
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess it was too optimistic to hope for something cleaner to read and write.